# How to convert a list of arrays to JSON array in php?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using fonoapi to display contents into my android app using volley. Volley requires data to be in JSON format while the php code returns data as an array(later modified by me but not getting proper JSON).

Here is the php -

```
<?php

    include_once("fonoapi-v1.php");

    $apiKey = "apiKey";
    $fonoapi = fonoApi::init($apiKey);

        try {

            $res = $fonoapi::getDevice("Samsung");

            foreach ($res as $mobile) {

                                $arr = [];
                                $arr['Device'] = $mobile->DeviceName;
                                $arr['Brand'] = $mobile->Brand;
                                $arr['Cpu'] = $mobile->cpu;
                                $arr['Status'] = $mobile->status;
                                $arr['Dimensions'] = $mobile->dimensions;
                                $arr['4g'] = $mobile->_4g_bands;
                        $json_arr = json_encode($arr);
                                echo $json_arr;

            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "ERROR : " . $e->getMessage();
        }

?>
```

Here is the response i am getting from php -

```
{
    "Device": "Samsung SGH-250",
    "Brand": "Samsung",
    "Cpu": null,
    "Status": "Discontinued",
    "Dimensions": "124 x 48 x 25 mm (4.88 x 1.89 x 0.98 in)",
    "4g": null
} {
    "Device": "Samsung SGH-500",
    "Brand": "Samsung",
    "Cpu": null,
    "Status": "Discontinued",
    "Dimensions": "112 x 48 x 19 mm (4.41 x 1.89 x 0.75 in)",
    "4g": null
} {
    "Device": "Samsung SGH-600",
    "Brand": "Samsung",
    "Cpu": null,
    "Status": "Discontinued",
    "Dimensions": "108 x 44 x 21 mm (4.25 x 1.73 x 0.83 in)",
    "4g": null
}
```

There are more results, i am showing only 3. I want the proper json format required to be printed like shown below -

```
{
    domain : [
        {
            Device : "Samsung SGH-250",
            Brand : "Samsung",
            Cpu : null,
            Status : "Discontinued",
            Dimensions : "124 x 48 x 25 mm (4.88 x 1.89 x 0.98 in)",
            4g : null
        },
        {
            Device : "Samsung SGH-500",
            Brand : "Samsung",
            Cpu : null,
            Status : "Discontinued",
            Dimensions : "112 x 48 x 19 mm (4.41 x 1.89 x 0.75 in)",
            4g : null
        },
        {
            Device : "Samsung SGH-600",
            Brand : "Samsung",
            Cpu : null,
            Status : "Discontinued",
            Dimensions : "108 x 44 x 21 mm (4.25 x 1.73 x 0.83 in)",
            4g : null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: `$domain[] = $arr;` then encode it after foreach loop `echo json_encode($domain);`

Comment: i wrote an answer so easily for you to copy it

Answer (score 0):

Try to gather all data before using echo:

```
$response = array();

    try {

        $res = $fonoapi::getDevice("Samsung");

        foreach ($res as $mobile) {

                            $arr = [];
                            $arr['Device'] = $mobile->DeviceName;
                            $arr['Brand'] = $mobile->Brand;
                            $arr['Cpu'] = $mobile->cpu;
                            $arr['Status'] = $mobile->status;
                            $arr['Dimensions'] = $mobile->dimensions;
                            $arr['4g'] = $mobile->_4g_bands;

                    $response[] = $arr;

        }

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "ERROR : " . $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo json_encode(array('domain'=>$response));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're echoing out one Json converted array at a time. What you need to do is make one larger array that contains all of the data and then convert that one larger array.

```
<?php

include_once('fonoapi-v1.php');

$apiKey = 'apiKey';
$fonoapi = fonoApi::init($apiKey);

try {

    $res = $fonoapi::getDevice('Samsung');

    $phones = array();

    foreach($res as $mobile) {
        $phones[] = array(
            'Device' => $mobile->DeviceName,
            'Brand' => $mobile->Brand,
            'Cpu' => $mobile->cpu,
            'Status' => $mobile->status,
            'Dimensions' => $mobile->dimensions,
            '4g' => $mobile->_4g_bands
        );
    }

    $json_arr = json_encode($phones);
    echo $json_arr;

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'ERROR : ', $e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the example reference you provided you can do something like this (gist of the code you need to change):

```
$response = [];
$response['domain'] = [];

foreach ($res as $mobile)
{
    $arr = [];
    $arr['Device'] = $mobile->DeviceName;
    $arr['Brand'] = $mobile->Brand;
    $arr['Cpu'] = $mobile->cpu;
    $arr['Status'] = $mobile->status;
    $arr['Dimensions'] = $mobile->dimensions;
    $arr['4g'] = $mobile->_4g_bands;

    $response['domain'][] = $arr;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: In this line - $response['domain'][] = $arr; What is the meaning of using [] brackets before the equals sign.

Comment: @GauravGupta It creates an indexed array, it increments the index number every time a new array is added. So, after `$response['domain'][] = $arr;` has inserted the first array, the response would contain the first indexed array which could be accessed like this `$response['domain'][0]`. Using the [] (square brackets) is the equivalent of using array().

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
$domain = array();
foreach ($res as $mobile) {

                            $arr = [];
                            $arr['Device'] = $mobile->DeviceName;
                            $arr['Brand'] = $mobile->Brand;
                            $arr['Cpu'] = $mobile->cpu;
                            $arr['Status'] = $mobile->status;
                            $arr['Dimensions'] = $mobile->dimensions;
                            $arr['4g'] = $mobile->_4g_bands;
                    //$json_arr = json_encode($arr);
                            //echo $json_arr;
$domain[] = $arr;

        }
echo json_encode(array('domain' => $domain));
```